# 4G dongle (for wireless internet) not detecting unless i restart ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb, usb-modem

I have a Airtel 4G LTE dongle. if i connect it to my laptop while laptop is on dongle is not getting detected.
It only gets detected if i restart laptop.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution [here](http://krblogs.com/post/62519969772/airtel-4g-lte-on-linux). In summary, you have to create a HTML file and put the following code:

```
form action = "http://192.168.0.1/goform/goform_set_cmd_process" method = "post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="goformId" value="CONNECT_NETWORK" checked style="display:none;">
 <BUTTON name="submit" type="submit"> Connect </BUTTON>
</form>

<form action = "http://192.168.0.1/goform/goform_set_cmd_process" method = "post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="goformId" value="DISCONNECT_NETWORK" checked style="display:none;">
 <BUTTON name="submit" type="submit"> Disconnect </BUTTON>
</form>
```

After connecting your dongle, open this html page in your browser and click `connect`.